# passing NVARCHAR value to stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure with `NVARCHAR` parameter like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[hr_Companies_GetByIDAndName] 
    @CompanyName NVARCHAR(100),
    @Lang int = 1
AS

Select * from companies
where
(@Lang = 1 AND NameLang1 LIKE @CompanyName )
    OR
    (@Lang = 2 AND NameLang2 LIKE  @CompanyName )
    )
```

I want to supply it a nvarchar value so I am using this syntax:

```
DBHelper _helper = new DBHelper();
_helper.StoredProc = "hr_Companies_GetByIDAndName";               
_helper.AddParam("@CompanyName", "N'%" + company.Trim() + "%'", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
_helper.AddParam("@Lang", Language, SqlDbType.Int);
return _helper.GetTable();
```

But it is returning `null`.

When I run query without stored procedure `select * from companies where companyname like N'%mycompanyname%'`, it returns result.

How to add `N` using `DBHelper` `addparameter`?

Comment: Try it without the N' in your AddParam.

Comment: then it doesn't work with non English characters 111კომპანია

Comment: Then I suspect there's something else wrong in how you access the database. I'm working with Arabic and Hewbrew and do not need to specify 'N' as part of the actual content string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your DBHelper does but to pass nvarchar type values to stored procs, following is the standard way:

```
var param = new SqlParameter("@CompanyName ", SqlDbType.NVarChar, size)
param.Value = company.Trim();
```

The 3rd parameter above is size of nvarchar parameter that is declared in sproc using `nvarchar(size)` syntax. If it is `nvarchar(max)` then use -1.

Also note that you don't need to use "N %" prefix. ADO.Net layer takes care of it.

Comment: I need N for Non english characters like 111კომპანია

Comment: You should not because .Net strings are already Unicode. You need N in tsql strings. This is of course, unless, you are using parameter value to build dynamic sql.